# How to restrict by an aggregate function without using it

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, having

Suppose I have a table like this (yes I am a Trekkie)...

```
CREATE TABLE starship_first_contacts (
  first_contact_id ID,
  starship_code CHAR,
  first_contact_species VARCHAR (40),
  first_contact_date DATE);
```

and I want to see how many ships have made over 10 first contacts, so I write a SQL like this..

```
select count(*), 
       starship_code
from starship_first_contacts 
group by starship_code
having count (*) > 10
```

But if I want to see what are those ships with over 10 first contacts, how would the SQL look like?

Ideally in the result set I would like a list of starship_codes and how many first contacts they each made and only want those which made over 10.

Comment: You want filter result for the starship with some number of years? or filter the group with count is certain value?

Comment: I don't think your SQL does what you describe.  In order to see how many ships have over 10 years of service, I would write a query similar to `select count(*) from starships where years_of_service > 10;` Can you please clarify what you are after and why you think you need to use aggregate functions at all?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thank you for pointing out the errors in my example table and SQL, I believe I have fixed them both now so any help you can offer in answering the actual question would be even further appreciated by yours truly.

Comment: @erdomke, you are right, my original SQL and example was wrong, could you please check my updates and offer any insight?

Comment: dude, if you just want starship_codes, how many first contacts they made and only those made over 10. your sql already done that.

Comment: and your sql did not tell you how many ships have made over 10 first contacts it only tells you the ship code, how many contacts they made and limited those are made over 10

Comment: You never said what is your rdbms, Sql Server, postgres, oracle, MySql ? Also some sample data and desire output help a lot into finding the correct answer. Beacuse your query looks correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how many ships have made over 10 first contacts

```
select count(*)
from (select starship_code
    from starship_first_contacts 
    group by starship_code
    having count (*) > 10
    ) as active
```

> what are those ships with over 10 first contacts

```
select starship_code
from starship_first_contacts 
group by starship_code
having count (*) > 10
```

Note that the first uses the second. It seems like maybe you think you have to write the second query in terms of the first but it's the other way around.

> Ideally in the result set I would like a list of starship_codes and how many first contacts they each made and only want those which made over 10.

That's the query in your question now:

> ```
> select count(*), 
>        starship_code
> from starship_first_contacts 
> group by starship_code
> having count (*) > 10
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to "I want to see how many ships have made over 10 first contacts, so I write a SQL like this" might look like.

```
select count(*)
From (
  Select
   starship_code
  from starship_first_contacts 
  group by starship_code
  having count (*) > 10
) d
```

However, the answer to your second question is the SQL you posted of

```
select count(*), 
   starship_code
from starship_first_contacts 
group by starship_code
having count (*) > 10
```